# Jboss contextRoot in EJB3 without web component

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb-3.0

I have an EAR **without a WAR** but with an EJB-JAR. One EJB inside the JAR exposes a service with **@WebService**. All works, but I don't know how control the urlcontext of the exposed service. Now it's something like:

http://jbossServer/myearnamepackage-myjarnamepackage/myEndoint?wsdl

I would like it to be:

http://jbossServer/myservice/myEndoint?wsdl

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the context root of your web service with the following annotations in your ejb3 bean:- `@WebContext(contextRoot="/myservice", urlPattern="/myEndpoint")`

This should make the web service wsdl bind to `http://jbossServer/myservice/myEndpoint?wsdl`

Comment: org.jboss.wsf.spi.annotation.WebContext из jboss-specific annotation that enforces another jar dependency and weakens app's portability.

Comment: Since JBoss 5 the same can be done with <webservices><context-root> in jboss.xml. See http://community.jboss.org/message/339266#339266.